# Content Missing Under Sticky Header

Tags: html, css, header, sticky

My site has a sticky header (position: fixed), which I understand from other posts takes the header out of the main flow and can be rectified  with extra padding to the body. However in this case it doesn't work. No matter where I add the padding the main content Header and part of the Para are lost behind the fixed header.

**This is only on the homepage and on screens smaller than 692px.**
http://www.mindfulnessperth.com.au

All other pages are fine!

Comment: You need to use media queries and readjust your padding or margin or both

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have idea of responsive web development and working with media queries?

If yes, then proceed with these changes in your custom.css on your wordpress.

```
    .home .site-header {top:0}

    @media (max-width:693px) {
    body {padding-top:150px} /* adjust it manually,depending upon ur browser width using media queries */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simple pushed down the next Element after the position: fixed header.

```
  @media (max-width:693px) {
      .site-inner {
       margin-top: 250px;
      }
    }
```